# when is the time to create indexes on your sql server db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Is it practice to create indexes for your sql server db at the start of the table creation?
or is it depending on how the performance ( or rather lack of ) is for this table so create this later?

Comment: This is a very very broad subject...

Comment: Some indexes could be estimated at the time of planning a product. The necessity for others might arise later, after deploying the product.

Comment: (1) always create a **good** clustered index on your tables, (2) index your foreign key columns (to speed up JOINs etc.), and (3) observe your system. If you encounter perf problems, analyze which additional indices might be helpful - add one or two - observe again. Don't over-index - indexes carry overhead, and having indexes that aren't being used is worse than having no indexes at all.

Comment: Depends upon your DB's performance and amount of data being stored in your DB on daily basis. By Default a clustered index is created on  your table when you set a column as primary key in your table. When data is increased in that table i.e. more than 10,000+ and your Stored Procedures are taking long time (more than 4 seconds) in case rows are more than 10000+  to fetch data after joining two or more tables. then you should consider implementing indexes. Also implementing indexes slower down performance while updating and inserting data in tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index are useful while retrieving data from tables HAVING HIGH VOLUMES of data. It is generally applied on id fields used in joins. Although they are extremely costly when there is bulk insertion/updates on those tables.
regarding the question that when they should be created : According to the best design practices, table structure/designing should be done initially as during design time a developer must know the purpose of the table. So how much data would be there in the table would be known to developer and hence indexes should be made initially

For reference :

http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-index.htm

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/